# How does particle size affect the elasticity of a collision between two particles?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, particle-physics, collision, elasticity

Lets say two particles in an aerosol collide. How does the size of the particles help determine if the collision is elastic or inelastic?

I am specifically referring to the following quote.

> It appears that a lot of MZ2 particles deposit together (Figure 2c), and their particle size is in the range of 0.5–2 μm, which may match the sizes of the particulate phase in smoke (from 0.1 to 1.0 μm) so that the elastic collision easily happens.
>   ([Hierarchical Composites to Reduce N-Nitrosamines in Cigarette Smoke](https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1944/8/3/1325/htm))

I am very confused as to why the size of the particles colliding would have any impact on if the collision is elastic. Can someone explain this?

Comment: in physics there is a definition what elastic means: no change in energy and only direction changes. elasticity is a different definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticity_(physics)